# Find next smallest key (performance advice needed)

Tags: java, algorithm, list, search, dictionary

I need some advice in terms of performance. I've got a `Map<DateTime, String>`. And I need something like the following method:

```
Map<DateTime, BigDecimal> map; // about 50 entries. Btw: Which impl to choose?

BigDecimal findNextSmaller(DateTime input) {

    DateTime tmp = null;

    for(DateTime d : map.keySet()) {
        if(tmp == null && d < input) {
            tmp = d;
        }
        if(d < input && d > tmp) {
            tmp = d;
        }
    }

    return map.get(tmp);
}
```

So basically I just iterate over the keySet of my `Map` and try to find the key which is the next smallest compared to `input`.

This method will get called about 1.000.000 times in a row:

```
BigDecimal sum;

List<Item> items; // about 1.000.000 Items

for(Item i : items) {
    sum = sum.add(findNextSmaller(i.getDateTime()));
}
```

Now I'm looking for a way to make things faster.

My first thought was to make an `OrderedList` out of the `Map`'s keySet. So in average I just have to iterate over half of the `DateTime`s. And then just do a `map.get(dateTimeFromOrderedList)` to get the matching value.

But is that all I can do about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a TreeMap which has a [built-in method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#ceilingEntry%28K%29) for that:

```
TreeMap<DateTime, BigDecimal> map = new TreeMap<>();
//populate the map

BigDecimal findNextSmaller(DateTime input) {
    return map.ceilingEntry(input).getValue(); //add exception checking as required
}
```

Note: you may want `ceilingEntry` or `higherEntry` depending on whether you want (resp.) `>=` or `>`.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [NavigableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html). This seems to be exactly what you need.

As you are searching for the DateTime closest and strictly less than the input, I would choose floorEntry(key) for the lookup. But make sure that you are handling nulls correctly. There may not be a key in the map that is strictly smaller than the input! If you try to add a null reference to a BigDecimal, a NullPointerException will be thrown.